# mysql foreign key as primary key error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am facing foreign key error in my SQL. My mySQL tables are

```
create table if not exists table1(
cust_name varchar(30) not null,
cust_phone char(16) not null,
cust_mail char(30) not null,
cust_address varchar(100),
bills int(10),
primary key (cust_name)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

create table if not exists table2 (
camp_id varchar(30) not null,
advr_id varchar(30) not null,
foreign key (advr_id) references table1 (cust_name),
primary key (camp_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

create table if not exists table3(
ad_id varchar(30) not null,
camp_id varchar(30) not null,
foreign key (camp_id) references table2(camp_id),
primary key (ad_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

create table if not exists counter(
ad_id varchar(30) not null,
foreign key (ad_id) references table3(ad_id),
PRIMARY KEY(ad_id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

When I run above commands, I get follwoing error.

> ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 96: Cannot add foreign key constraint

What is the problem?

Comment: This executes without any problems on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/224f5)

Comment: Try removing the `ad_id varchar(30) not null,` from table `counter`.

Comment: @Shafiq you should check data in table first, may that creating issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error when I run this code. I think their might be some spelling mistakes in your origional code. Try to use mysql gui application for details of logs. It will precisely point the error.

Comment: Thanks, That was the issue I find, It was just an spelling (name) mistake

Answer (score 1):

There is no any error. This is run without error.

```
mysql> create table if not exists table1(
    -> cust_name varchar(30) not null,
    -> cust_phone char(16) not null,
    -> cust_mail char(30) not null,
    -> cust_address varchar(100),
    -> bills int(10),
    -> primary key (cust_name)
    -> )ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.08 sec)


mysql> create table if not exists table2 (
    -> camp_id varchar(30) not null,
    -> advr_id varchar(30) not null,
    -> foreign key (advr_id) references table1 (cust_name),
    -> primary key (camp_id)
    -> )ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.10 sec)


mysql> create table if not exists table3(
    -> ad_id varchar(30) not null,
    -> camp_id varchar(30) not null,
    -> foreign key (camp_id) references table2(camp_id),
    -> primary key (ad_id)
    -> )ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.37 sec)


mysql> create table if not exists counter(
    -> ad_id varchar(30) not null,
    -> foreign key (ad_id) references table3(ad_id),
    -> PRIMARY KEY(ad_id)
    -> )ENGINE=INNODB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)
```

I Execute in my database but there is no any error or warning